# Create variables from an array of cells in Matlab

Tags: matlab, eval, cell, cell-array

I have an array of cells, for example,

`cells = {'a', 'b', 'c', d', 'e'};`

which is inside a for loop of 1 to 5.

I want to create a variable from a to e depending on the loop index, as 1 to a, 2 to b...

When I try (`i` is the for index),

`eval(cells{i}) = values;` it gives me the error,

`Undefined function or method 'eval' for input arguments of type 'a'`

Comment: Do not do that! There are better approaches than puffing variables into the workspace. http://matlab.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ#How_can_I_create_variables_A1.2C_A2.2C....2CA10_in_a_loop.3F look at the third solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the answer:

```
eval(sprintf([cells{i} '=values;']))
```

And you can remove the `;` if you want to see the display in command window.

In answer to your comment :

```
cells = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
values = 4;
i = 1;
eval(sprintf([cells{i} '=values;']))
```

This works perfectly fine on my computer, and i get no warning or error messages.

Comment: It does not work for me, it gives me this error, `The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment.`

Answer (score 0):

when calling eval, all arguments must be strings, so convert your cell elements to strings first.

```
eval([ cellstr(cells{i}) ' = values;']))
```